# Custom query send email notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, alert

I have a custom query "issue" in SharePoint 2010 and I'm trying to find how I can add notification on it.

So that each time I add data in it, it will send an email to some users

Comment: I have three work Item in dashboard : Bug, Issue , Task  and I would like that my team can receive a notification each time  a bug or issue or a task is added .

Comment: Sorry its sharepoint 2010 not 13

Comment: I've edited your question accordingly:)

Comment: I created a workflow bugnotification in sharepoint deisgner but I dont know how I can associate that with a query, For each entry in "bug" query can use the workflow

Comment: Here we go for another comment maybe someone can help me !! I can see my queries pages Aspx,Html but I still look for a possibility to link it with my workflow ....